# Web API routing with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to setup routing for my WEBAPI to have few methods with paramater and few without parameters. I want to use my function names in the controller in the actual urls to be used for actions. To explain it more, here is my routing mapping:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Here are the two functions I add:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Category> FunctionWithParam(long param)
    {
        //return something
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Category> FunctionWithoutParam()
    {
       //return something
    }
```

When I hit: 
            **root/api/controller name/FunctionWithoutParam** 
it does call the appropriate function. But I cannot call FunctionWithParam. I tried
**root/api/controller name/FunctionWithParam/10**
But this does not seem to work. I put a breakpoint and the function with parmater is just not called. What am I doing wrong, How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please specify what exact problem you are facing or what exception it is throwing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function parameter name to match the route:

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Category> FunctionWithParam(long id)
    {
        //return something
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am afraid I could have ever realized it!!